# How to find if parameter of a function divided by 2 is NaN?

Tags: javascript

I am needing to write a function that takes in a parameter. If the parameter divided by 2 is NaN it is to return "FLYING NOCTURNAL MAMMAL MAN!" Otherwise it is to return the result of the parameter divided by 2. I feel like what I am trying is pretty close. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here is what I am trying:

```
nananan = (num) => {
  if(num/2 == isNaN(num) || isNaN(num)) {
    return "FLYING NOCTURNAL MAMMAL MAN!";
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}
```

Comment: `isNaN(num / 2)` ?

Comment: The only way this would occur is if `isNaN(num)` itself was also true.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a shitpost or I'm not seeing something here...

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco [This may enlighten you](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). Skip to 3:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
nan = (num) => {
    if (isNaN(num/2)) return "FLYING NOCTURNAL MAMMAL MAN!"
    else return num/2
}

console.log(nan(2))
console.log(nan('a'))
```

Comment: Clearly the function must be named `nananan` or it is not valid ;) (kidding, of course)

Comment: if my answer is correct, please mark it as the right answer so your question can be closed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's easy: `4`. In fact any number at all that isn't `NaN`, `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, `0`, or `-0`.

Comment: Ah, that's the part you were fixated on... to be fair, that's not clear unless you're completely dismissing the attempted implementation.

Answer (score 2):

so the following codes should work

```js
nananan = (num) => {
  if(isNaN(num)) {
    return "FLYING NOCTURNAL MAMMAL MAN!";
  } else {
    return num/2;
  }
}

console.log(nananan()); //now its NAN
console.log(nananan('adf')); //now its NAN
console.log(nananan(1)); //now its not a NAN
console.log(nananan(-1)); //now its not a NAN
```

so the logic here is that `num/2` will only be NAN if the num itself is NAN. so why check `isNaN(num/2)` just `isNaN(num)` should do.

Comment: dear down voter can you please explain why down vote? so i can improve?

Comment: It should return `num/2` in the else clause.

Comment: True, but he said it should "return the result of the parameter divided by 2". I'm pretty sure the original code didn't work at all and the OP thought that `num/2` in the if statement mutated `num`, so that all future usage was already divided by 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this more concise using a [conditional ternary `?` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
const nananan = num => isNaN(num) ? 'FLYING NOCTURNAL MAMMAL MAN!' : num / 2;
```

As I mentioned in comments, while `isNaN(num / 2)` is indeed the condition you were looking for, it is true if and only if `isNaN(num)` is true.